# url rewrite advise for categories & sub categories

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

currently my website has around 40 main categories & around 250 sub categories and around 10K products.

my current url is like this....

```
site.com/1/electroncis (main category)
site.com/2/Headphones ( electronics > headphones)
```

----now there are many parent and sub categories

what I want to do is following...

```
site.com/electroncis (main category)
site.com/electroncis/headphones (main > sub)
```

I have `ID`'s in url's so in my code i can grab the `categoryID` and return those matching products, my tables perform lookups using `CategoryID` (not the category name).
to accomplish what i want...do I need to create over 500 static rules within my `web.config` file? there has to be a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the ID inside a typical URL scheme, something like `http://example.com/CatID` or `http://example.com/folder/folder/CatID`, for example? ¿Is the category ID numeric only? Please include one example.

Comment: CatID is always number. Site.com/1/phone rewrites to site.com/cat.asp?id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really think its possible. clostest solution I came up with is to create rewriteMaps with key/value pairs

```
<add key="cars" value="page.asp?v=1" />
<add key="car/suvs" value="page.asp?v=2" />
```

I can generate above tags using .NET and paste them into a .config file.

Comment: Or i can store these values within SQL server. Much easier to manage using any crm.